# Tags HTML nao reconhecidas

Tags: java, html, html5, controller

Ola, estou fazendo um codigo com java e html e preciso fazer uma lista com Objetos vindos do Controller. estou tentando usar a tag `<li>` la mas ao inves de trasnformar uma lista ele imprime o `<li>`, ficando da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

este primeiro `<li>` que funcionou aí, foi que eu coloquei no proprio html, para teste... mas eu precisaria de algo que fizesse a lista para cada item.

meu codigo java:

```
if (tipos.size() > 0)
            {
                String vinculos = "";
                for (Entidade entidade : tipos) {
                    vinculos += "<li>" + entidade.getNome() + ";</li>";
                }               

                ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("tipoadministracao/createedit", "model", model);
                //return BusinessException.addInfo(modelView, attributes, model.getNome(), vinculos);
                return BusinessException.ExceptionToViewInfo(modelView, model.getNome(), vinculos, "/tipoadministracao");

            }else
            {
                service.delete(id,  model);
                ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/tipoadministracao");
                return BusinessException.addSuccess(modelView, attributes, "Exclusão realizada com sucesso!");
            }
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
                            <ul>
                                <li> [[${infoVinculos}]]</li>                           
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

**EDIT 1**:
Já corrigi uma observação apontada pelo Sam, em um comentário. Apenas utilizei um if para verificar se ja existia um vinculo, enfim... o novo resultado está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma observação: se `[[${infoVinculos}]]` já vem com `<li>`, não precisava colocar outra `<li>` no HTML.

Comment: sim, obrigado pela observação, mas por enquando só estou testando pra ver se ele vai ler, depois que vou corrigir esses detalhes.

Comment: Não consegui entender qual é a sua dúvida

Comment: entao Leandro, se você observar a imagem, ele escreve a tag <li>, ao inves de transformá-la em um item da lista, eu gostaria que cada escrita dentro da tag virasse um item desta lista que eu criei